# Is it possible to pull on- premises SQL server data into SharePoint page using spfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx-webparts, sql-server

I have a requirement like , have to pull on-premises SQL server data in to SharePoint online page using spfx without importing into the SP list?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

1. Create an authenticated API (I would use a .NET API project), making
       sure to use keep the connection strings in the project configuration
       (web.config/settings .json) -- see Part I of [this
       article](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/on-premise-apis/)
2. On one of your servers, install and configure an [on-premises data
       gateway](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-onprem). The steps are similar to [Step 3 of this article](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/on-premise-apis/)
3. Deploy your API to Azure. Keep the connection string the same. Azure
   should resolve the connection string and route traffic through
       the gateway.
4. Create a web part that calls the authenticated API to query the data.

It is a very over-simplified list of steps, but it should get you started.

Let me know if you need more detailed instructions.

Comment: Hi Hugo
 Can you provide some detailed steps or article regarding this?

Comment: @Parthasarathy I'll write an article and update this discussion with the link.